# Biztalk File Polling

Tags: biztalk, polling

I want to make a receive location in Biztalk 2010 that will poll for a file just just once a day.

If one file is moved it should stop polling again. Because when the file is moved another application can create a new file in that directory just 1 millisecond later, and that new file may not be moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your receive location on a schedule to receive only within a given time frame. Dealing with milliseconds however it would be a bad idea to try to control your receive location with timing.

Depending on your requirements I would configure the receive location to only pick up a file with a given name (not a wildcard *.txt) or have your other application create its file in a different location altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Filburt, scheduling is not the answer here. You may be able to create an orchestration that only processes once a day, and queues up the other files. However, if the existence of that file is somehow 'gating' the other system then this is bad design up front.

Answer (score -1):

Open the receive location properties and click "Configure" next to the FILE type dropdown.

Click Advanced settings, change the Polling interval to 3600000 (one hour). Click OK.

Click the "Batching" tab. Change "Number of messages in a batch:" to 1. Click OK.

Go to the "Schedule" pane. Check "Enable service window."

Set the service window to whenever you want this to run. Make sure you make the window less than 1 hour.

This should do what you want. You can make it less than one hour or any time range, but the service window range must be less than the Polling interval.

Comment: Is this solution documented in the msdn?

Comment: Sorry, this is only valid for non-Windows filesystems.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx

The Directory Change Notification will always trigger the File adapter. I am sorry for my faulty response. I'd forgotten that this doesn't override the notification based behavior.